# How to compare .docx files with PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, compare, docx

How can I compare **character count**, **word count** and **formatting** of two `.docx` files with either `PHP` or `JavaScript`?

Comment: There are libraries for PHP for reading docx files. i really doubt if you would get a js library that could do the job here.

Comment: I know there are libraries to read docx file but I want to do much more than just reading which I have not found in any library

Comment: If you read through the libraries' documentation, and look into how you may be able to detect the formatting, and try to see if you can do it. Then, if you experience issues, create a question that expresses your need for help on that.

Comment: can u please suggest me any library ??

Comment: i have used https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord before. you can try that to start with...

Comment: what have you searched or tried so far ? where is your code ?